# SqlBulkCopy DataTables as they are added to a DataSet

Tags: c#, sql-server, asynchronous, sqlbulkcopy

I'd like to parse values from a csv into datatable chunks, add them to a dataset, and then use SQLBulkCopy to insert the datatables into a single table in SQL.  The original csv can range from 4 GB to 8 GB, and I need to avoid reading the entire thing into memory, hence the chunking.  I loosely based my chunking on this [post](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/543789/Parse-CSV-file-chunk-by-chunk-and-save-in-database). I use [LumenWorks](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader) to parse the csv values.

As soon as a datatable is added to the dataset, I want to use SqlBulkCopy to insert it into my SQL table, all while the next datatable is being created.  After the SqlBulkCopy completes, I want to remove the datatable to release the memory.

My first thought is to run the chunking method asynchronously without await, then run a while loop that checks for the existence of a next datatable in the dataset.  If the datatable exists, then bulk copy.  If the datatable row count is less then the row limit, then it is the last chunk and stop while loop.

Am I going about this the wrong way?  If not, how can I do something like this?

```
        string filePath = @"C:\Users\user\Downloads\Testing\file - Copy.csv";
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        bool continueInsert = true;
        int rowLimit = 100000;
        int tableNumber = 0;

        //Start this, but do not wait for it to complete before starting while loop
        ChunkCSV(filePath, ds, rowLimit);

        //Run SqlBulkCopy if datatable exists 
        while (continueInsert)
        {
            if (ds.Tables.Contains("tbl_" + tableNumber))
            {
                DataTable dataTable = ds.Tables["tbl_" + tableNumber];

                //SqlBulkCopy dataTable code HERE

                if (ds.Tables["tbl_" + tableNumber].Rows.Count < rowLimit)
                {
                    continueInsert = false;
                }

                //Remove datatable from dataset to release memory
                ds.Tables.Remove("tbl_" + tableNumber);

                tableNumber++;
            }
            else
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }
```

Here is my chunking code:

```
    private static void ChunkCSV(string filePath, DataSet dataSet, int rowLimit)
    {
        char delimiter = ',';

        DataTable dtChunk = null;
        int tableNumber = 0;
        int chunkRowCount = 0;
        bool firstLineOfChunk = true;

        using (var sr = new StreamReader(filePath))
        using (CsvReader csv = new CsvReader(sr, false, delimiter, '\"', '\0', '\0', ValueTrimmingOptions.All, 65536))
        {
            int fieldCount = csv.FieldCount;
            string[] row = new string[fieldCount];

            //Add fields when necessary
            csv.MissingFieldAction = MissingFieldAction.ReplaceByEmpty;

            while (csv.ReadNextRecord())
            {
                if (firstLineOfChunk)
                {
                    firstLineOfChunk = false;
                    dtChunk = CreateDataTable(fieldCount, tableNumber);
                }

                DataRow dataRow = dtChunk.NewRow();

                csv.CopyCurrentRecordTo(row);
                for (int f = 0; f < fieldCount; f++)
                {
                    dataRow[f] = row[f];
                }

                dtChunk.Rows.Add(dataRow);
                chunkRowCount++;

                if (chunkRowCount == rowLimit)
                {
                    firstLineOfChunk = true;
                    chunkRowCount = 0;
                    tableNumber++;
                    dataSet.Tables.Add(dtChunk);
                    dtChunk = null;
                }
            }
        }

        if (dtChunk != null)
        {
            dataSet.Tables.Add(dtChunk);
        }

    }
    private static DataTable CreateDataTable(int fieldCount, int tableNumber)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable("tbl_" + tableNumber);

        for(int i = 0; i < fieldCount; i++)
        {
            dt.Columns.Add("Column_" + i);
        }

        return dt;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no reason to use a DataTable to begin with.

Use the [SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(IDataReader)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.writetoserver?view=netframework-4.8#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlBulkCopy_WriteToServer_System_Data_IDataReader_) overload, and you can stream the whole file directly to SQL Server.  And use [SqlBulkCopy.BatchSize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.batchsize?view=netframework-4.8) if you don't want all the rows loaded in a single transaction.

eg

```
using (var sr = new StreamReader(filePath))
using (CsvReader csv = new CsvReader(sr, false, delimiter, '\"', '\0', '\0', ValueTrimmingOptions.All, 65536))
{
    bulkCopy.WriteToServer(csv);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't streaming the whole file directly to the SQL Server result in reading the entire file into memory, what the OP is trying to avoid?

Comment: Nope.  So long as the IDataReader implementation reads the file line-by-line, it will be streaming all the way to SQL Server.

Comment: so you're saying there's no need for the `CsvReader` then either, and all the CSV parsing is done in SQL?

Comment: No the CsvReader still does the parsing, and implements the IDataReader interface, which SqlBulkCopy knows how to read from.

Comment: Hmm. I guess I was thrown off by the OP's remark about using LumenReader to parse CSV values. I may have had the impression the OP was doing further processing. That's an elegant solution

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I use the CsvReader because sometimes the CSV rows will have inconsistent field counts, and the CsvReader will add fields when necessary.  I must be missing something though - I only see IDataReader being used to read data from a SQL source.

Comment: The CSVReader you are using implements the IDataReader interface already.  `public partial class CsvReader
  : IDataReader, IEnumerable<string[]>, IDisposable` And even if it didn't, you would be better of providing an IDataReader implementation for it than doing custom batching of data into DataTables.

Comment: Incredible!  So simple.  Thanks again.